# How to secure Cross Platform Application in Android

Tags: android, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, decompiler

I am developing cross platform application using sencha framework. I find the strange thing i.e it is  easy to decompile the apk file and get the asset (resource folder) from android. I want to hide all my project files exist inside the asset folder. Is it possible to hide the javascript and html content after decompiling using this [decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/.)

This is not far to see the entire source, there is anyother way to conceal this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand things, you need to somehow encrypt your app - because, as you point out, decompiling the source isn't all that difficult.

I don't know the specifics behind the process, but you might check out [Sencha Space](http://www.sencha.com/products/space/) which provides a secure wrapper for your apps.